# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to create a create button in visual basic so the record goes into my database but it get this error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

my code is here and i get the error on `da.Update(ds, "Test")`

```
Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Test").NewRow()

dsNewRow.Item("Username") = txtUsername.Text
dsNewRow.Item("Password") = txtPassword.Text
dsNewRow.Item("Email Address") = txtEmailAddress.Text

ds.Tables("Test").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

da.Update(ds, "Test")
```

any help would be amazing.

Comment: According to the error, It is related to your sql text. So I hope you can provide it with me so that I can do some test.

Answer (score 1):

When this error occurs with a command builder, it is generally because one or more of your column names is a reserved word or contains spaces or other special characters.  In your case, you have what is likely a reserved word, i.e. `Password`, and also a space in `Email Address`.

The first choice option should be to avoid such column names.  In this case, `Email Address` should be `EmailAddress`, just as you would use for an identifier in VB.  There's not necessarily an obvious alternative for `Password`, except that passwords should pretty much never be stored in the clear, so a real app should hash passwords and then the column could be named `PasswordHash`.

Failing that, you can set the `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` properties of your command builder so that your column names will be escaped.  In your case, "[" and "]" the the values you probably ought to be using, i.e.

```
cb.QuotePrefix = "["
cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"
```